# moment.js format date in TZ format

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I want to cast MySql datetime strings like

```
2018-05-17 15:03:31
```

to format like :

```
2018-05-17T15:03:31.000Z
```

How can I do that using moment.js library?

Comment: For future reference this question is the opposite of [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45101817/javascript-date-format-prefer-moment).

Answer (score 2):

Since you input is in ISO 8601 format, you can parse it using [`moment.utc`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) (see [Local vs UTC vs Offset](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/local-utc-zone/)), then you can simply use [`toISOString()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/):

> Note that `.toISOString()` returns a timestamp in UTC, even if the moment in question is in local mode. This is done to provide consistency with the specification for native JavaScript Date `.toISOString()`, as outlined in [the ES2015 specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype.toisostring). From version **2.20.0**, you may call `.toISOString(true)` to prevent UTC conversion.

```js
var input = '2018-05-17 15:03:31';
console.log( moment.utc(input).toISOString() );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```